# Simplify creation of compile-time binary tree type

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, metaprogramming, parameter-pack

In the context of creating a binary tree type for a larger C++ project, I need to create a compile time type representing the nodes in each level.

Does anyone know, using the newest standards, if there is a simpler, nicer looking way of creating the `LevelType`, for an arbitrary value of `nLevels` in the (very simplified) code below?

I just need the **type**, so I can define it for the class `Tree`.

Thank you!

```cpp
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

template <typename LevelType>
class Tree
{            
    public:
    LevelType level ;                                                                                                                                        
};

template <std::size_t nLevels, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto make_tree_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return Tree
    <typename std::remove_reference
    <decltype(std::make_tuple(std::array<double,1<<Is>()...))>::type>();
};

template <std::size_t nLevels>
constexpr auto make_tree()
{
    return make_tree_impl<nLevels>(std::make_index_sequence<nLevels>());
};

int main()
{
    const unsigned int nLevels = 5;
    auto tree = make_tree<nLevels>();
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(tree),
    Tree<std::tuple<std::array<double,1>,
                    std::array<double,2>,
                    std::array<double,4>,
                    std::array<double,8>,
                    std::array<double,16>>>>::value << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What C++ version? You don't really need the meta-programming anymore with recent C++ versions. With C++20 or later any normal tree implementation with `constexpr` should work at compile-time, possibly with some necessary adjustments to the allocation scheme. If you need to pass the tree to runtime as well, then you also need to make sure that your allocator allocates from a fixed array, the size of which you need to determine first.

Comment: Thank you. That's the key to my problem. For the class ```Tree``` I need the class ```LevelType```, that has to be created at compile time based on ```nLevels```. Just to create the type, is there a simpler way in c++23?

Comment: What exactly do you need? How is `Tree` supposed to be used? Why does the tree structure need to be encoded in the type?

Comment: Deducing functional requirements from code is a pain (and unreliable -- different people see different things). It would be better to write them out.

Comment: The exact requirements are important, because otherwise it is simple: `struct Tree { std::vector<Tree> children; };` works perfectly fine at compile-time in C++20 and later, but may not satisfy all the use cases you imagine.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you. I need to deduce the class ```LevelType```, based on the value of ```nLevels```, just to restate my question.

Comment: @user17732522 I understand your point, but just to keep my question narrow, I'd like to concentrate in how to get the ```LevelType``` instead of a larger overhaul.

Comment: @Astor OK, is `make_tree` supposed to only produce the type or an instance of it (as it does now)? If not, you can replace the function with an alias template.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks for you time! So, ```make_tree``` and ```make_tree_impl``` can be completely replaced or eliminated. I need a concise, readable way to create the class ```LevelType``` (which depends on ```nLevels```) so I can feed it as a template parameter to the class ```Tree<LevelType>```. Without using the pre-processor of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `std::remove_reference` because `make_tuple` returns a non-reference.

You don't need `std::make_tuple`. You can just specify the `std::tuple` directly.

You don't need `make_tree` to be a function. If you only want the type it can be an alias template.

And with the above you also don't need `make_tree_impl` to be defined, because it is only ever called to obtain the return type, which as a non-reference type again doesn't require a `remove_reference`:

```
template <auto... Is>
auto make_tree_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> Tree<std::tuple<std::array<double, std::size_t{1} << Is>...>>;

template <std::size_t nLevels>
using make_tree = decltype(make_tree_impl(std::make_index_sequence<nLevels>{}));
```

Then you get the type directly with:

```
using T = make_tree<nLevels>;
```

The `make_tree_impl` function can also be replaced with an equivalent lambda in C++20 and later, but it won't make it look more readable.