# Initializing variadic-template-constructed tuple of types with constructor requiring an argument

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, initialization, variadic

I apologize already having asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77119695/simplify-creation-of-compile-time-binary-tree-type/77119805#77119805) when I should have modified the question I asked first.

I have the class `Level` which constructor requires an argument.
Using variadic templates I create a type `LevelType` for a member of the class `Tree` which is a tuple of elements of type `Level`.

How can I avoid repeating the value `data` in the initialization list of `Tree`?

As a further constraint, it should be possible for objects of class `Tree` to be constructed at compile time, so as far as I know I need some kind of template metaprogramming-fu.

Thank you!

Here's a code snippet:

```cpp
#include<utility>
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

class LevelData
{};

template <typename LevelType>
class Level
{            
    public:
    Level(LevelData & data_):
    data(data_)
    {};

    LevelData & data ;
};

template <std::size_t nLevels,typename LevelType>
class Tree
{            
    public:
    Tree(LevelData & data):
    level(data,data,data,data,data)
    {};

    LevelType level ;                                                                                                                                        
};

template <std::size_t nLevels,auto... Is>
auto make_tree_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> Tree<nLevels,std::tuple<Level<std::array<double, std::size_t{1} << Is>>...>>;

template <std::size_t nLevels>
using make_tree = decltype(make_tree_impl<nLevels>(std::make_index_sequence<nLevels>{}));

int main()
{
    const unsigned int nLevels = 5;
    LevelData data;
    auto tree = make_tree<nLevels>(data);
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(tree),
    Tree<nLevels,std::tuple<Level<std::array<double,1>>,
                            Level<std::array<double,2>>,
                            Level<std::array<double,4>>,
                            Level<std::array<double,8>>,
                            Level<std::array<double,16>>>>>::value << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `make_index_sequence` again, only this time it's used to repeat `data` as many times as you have types in your `tuple`.

Unfolding can be done by using `(static_cast<void>(Is), data)...` since the left part of the `,` operator will be discarded, leaving only `data`, `sizeof...(Is)` number of times.

```cpp
template <std::size_t nLevels, typename LevelType>
class Tree {
public:
    Tree(LevelData& data)
        : level{[&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
              return LevelType{(static_cast<void>(Is), data)...};
          }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<LevelType>>())} {}

    LevelType level;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use this tuple wrapper:

```
// Like a tuple but has a one-argument ctor
// that replicates its arg to all tuple elements
template <class ... T>
struct tuple_wrapper : public std::tuple<T...>
{
  template <class P>
  tuple_wrapper(P&& p) : std::tuple<T...>((static_cast<std::void_t<T>>(0), 
                                           std::forward<P>(p))...) {}
  using std::tuple<T...>::tuple;
};
```

(I personally hate the hoops I have to jump through every time I need to use `std::index_sequence`).

Comment: This is nice but I think forwarding the same argument multiple times looks risky. Not with OPs types, but in general.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo . Could you elaborate on the risk? The ```Level``` class is in fact an elaborate one on my implementation.

Comment: @Astor If `p` is a `vector` or `string` or similar,  forwarding it could mean that the receiver "steals" its resources, leaving `p` in an indeterminate state, with the resources gone - so the next object you forward it to will get `p` in that shape. Therefore I'd skip forwarding in this case and just provide `p` as-is. It _is_ a nice solution though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is true, but... If the user's ctor steals resources, then perhaps duplicating `data` as in the original code is unsafe too. Note the original code has a non-const lvalue reference parameter, and the ctor can destructively modify it. Initially I just tried to pass everything by value but it didn't compile with the lvalue reference parameter to the ctor. So I added forwarding.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Since OP has a non-`const` `LevelData& data;` member in the receiving class it makes it hard to take it by  `const&` in the constructor. I'd still just pass `p` but perhaps forwarding _is_ the proper thing to do here after all :-)